# How can I add timestamp tags in a video for navigation?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I add timestamp tags in a video in a way that when any tag is clicked, the video player hops to that point?

Like it is on SoundCloud, it shows comments and when we click on any of the comments, it provides an option to add a reply.

When I am in editing mode and move to some point in the video, I want to add a tag at that point. When playing, the video player should display all the tags and by clicking on those tags, the player jumps to those point in the video.

I would like to implement using JavaScript and Ruby on Rails.

[Attachment for SoundCloud example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxppM.png)

Comment: To people who downvoted: clicking on a downvote button is too easy, thinking about how to improve the question is much harder but it is also more helpful, which makes SO great. Think twice before you downvote.

Comment: @OP: please edit your questions:
- It is confusing when you used JavaScript and RoR tags without attaching any sample code.
- Do you want timestamp tags in your video player? It is not the same as SoundCloud comment feature.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit naive but let's think about it for a bit. In essence what you want is a `PlayThrough` entity which acts as a sort of "session" where you can store the following:

- The `Video` tied to the `PlayThrough`
- The elapsed seconds in the `PlayThrough`
- The `User` tied to the `PlayThrough` (optional if done on backend)

Furthermore, depending on your requirements you might need to store this information on the backend or have it stored in the frontend. For the sake of simplicity let's assume we're storing it in the frontend, what you need to do is:

- When first loading the video, if there's no `PlayThrough` for it we create one with the video id.
- For every elapsed second of the current video we update the `PlayThrough` object with the amount of elapsed seconds.
- If there's a `PlayThrough` object we load the video data starting from where the elapsed seconds says it should.

The particular implementation on how to do these things is dependent on whether you're storing the data in the backend or in the frontend; furthermore, in the case of the frontend it'll depend on which framework you're using for your frontend application and how you're playing the video, if through a library that allows resume-play from a specific offset or you're rolling your own, etc.

Hopefully this high-level overview is a good starting point you can use to further refine the requirements for your solution.

Comment: i am thinking of using video js all i need is just the time of video when ever someone move to specific time by clicking seekbar i can then show a modal to get tag for that spot and save it in db

Comment: You got it, when you handle the seekbar change, pause the video, render the modal, do the save to the backend then on success, jump to the new time and resume the video